# Convert return value of "gzencode()" to UTF-8

Tags: php, string, utf-8, character-encoding, gzip

I need to send the gzip encoded HTML of a page via email, (don't tell me to send the HTML without compression). It doesn't work correctly because `gzencode()` doesn't return UTF-8 characters.

How could I convert the string that `gzencode()` returns, into UTF-8 string, and still be able to form the original string when I want to decode the gzip string?

Comment: I edited your question to use code blocks so that it is more readable and highlighted the problem. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more information on formatting.

Comment: Did you declare in the header of the email that the body is encoded with gzip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `utf8_encode()` to turn it into a utf8 string, and I will use a `utf8_decode()` or a similar way of converting it back to its original charset (I tested it, it works)